# Printing UTF-16 strings in JSP is outputted as HTML encoding (&#xxxx)

Tags: jsp

When I try to print a UTF-16 string in JSP, specifically Hebrew, it ends up showing up as HTML encoding (&#xxxx).

This problem occurs because I print an array of variables into the web page and then parse them. The variables are all UTF-16 strings, but once the servlet prints the variables, it becomes translated to HTML encoding. Is there any way to get rid of the encoding?

Thanks in advance

Edit for a bit more background:

The JSP that I'm printing is not the entirety of the page. It's used in a manner I don't quite understand by a server app which prints the JSPs output into its built in page. This isn't a frame or anything like that. It's just redirected output.

Comment: When you say "*showing* up as HTML encoding (&#xxxx)", do you mean that on whe wire it's really `&amp;#xxxx` ?

Comment: No, I mean that it's originally a real string, (actual letters) but they are translated by the servlet (I assume) to &#xxxx

Comment: That's not default JSP behaviour. You're using some MVC or templating framework you aren't aware of and not using it the right way. Ask your manager/architect/colleagues what framework it is. I would by the way also just communicate this problem to them, they may know the cause and solution. This by the way smells much like a XML based MVC framework like JSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if adding

```
contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

to the JSP header (`<%@page ...`) helps.

Comment: It didn't work. See my edit for a bit more clarification on the situation.

Comment: Also, I tried using UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 for the hell of it, but that completely botched everything up. I assume that wasn't meant to work.

Comment: @Ori: I'm not sure if UTF-16 is supported on the web at all.  Presumably it is, but I never saw it used.  Without details of how the page is generated it's hard to say more.  Look what and where calls `setContentType()` on `HttpServletResponse` object, it might be "wrong" (not UTF-8) or missing.  Also search for `setHeader()` call for `Content-Type` header — I'm not sure what of those takes precedence.

Comment: No, character encodings has nothing to do with instantly converting non-ASCII characters to XML entities. A different character encoding would only cause the XML entities being numbered differently :)

Comment: @BalusC: Isn't entity number the UCS codepoint?  I.e. isn't it independent from encoding?